# Android Emulator taking up whole screen

Tags: android, emulation

I am doing some Android programming tutorials, but when the emulator opens up it takes up most of the screen, which is much bigger than a normal phone looks like.

Here is a picture of my screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hodLM.jpg

And it doesn't let me resize the emulator.  Are all emulators this big, and is there any way to make it smaller or resize it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a smaller resolution.

Alternatively, if you want to keep the same resolution, you can change the property "Abstracted LCD density" and check "Scale display to real size" when you start the emulator. Increasing the density will make the emulator window proportionally smaller.

Comment: Thank you.  I had troubles finding the Scale display to real size option, but eventually found it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting a bigger desktop, or adjust scale of window when it starts. Also, i don't recommend changing the dpi because it blurs the icons (*framework-res.apk* has only *mdpi* and *hdpi* drawables i think).